# Typeorm/Postgres blog like constraint

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

im creating a blog where you can like a comment or a post with typeorm and postgres, here is the like entitie:

```
@Entity()
@Unique(["user", "post", "comment"])
export default class Like {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // @Column()
  // likeCount: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.likes, { nullable: false })
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Post, (post) => post.likes)
  post: Post;

  @ManyToOne(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.likes)
  comment: Comment;
```

I want to create a constraint where a user can like a comment/post only once, in the code above i tried with unique constraints but its not working, how should i do it? should i create two differents tables, one for like-post and one for like-comment? and how do i keep track of how many likes each comment/post have?

i tried unique constraint but is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a unique constraint **on the combination** of the user_id and comment_id columns, or the combination of the user_id and post_id columns. this **will allow a user to like more than one post/comment**. and use foreign keys to link likes with posts/comments to ensure they exist in the database

Comment: thank you very much, this was the problem, i was doing the 3 paramenters on the same unique constraint, but i had to do two different unique constraints, one with userid/postid and another with userid/commentid

Answer (score 0):

Add columns `userId`, `postId`, `commentId` and make a unique index on them.

Like this^

```js
@Entity()
@Unique(["userId", "postId", "commentId"])
export default class Like {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // @Column()
  // likeCount: number;

  @Column()
  userId: number;

  @Column()
  postId: number;

  @Column()
  commentId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.likes, { nullable: false })
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Post, (post) => post.likes)
  post: Post;

  @ManyToOne(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.likes)
  comment: Comment;
```

Thus, one **User** likes only one **Comment** per **Post**.

Comment: i tried this way but since i have a unique constraint on the userid i can only like one comment or one post with the same user

heres the entity after i did what you told me:

@Index({ unique: true  })
@Column({ nullable: true })
 postId: number;

i did the 3 new columns and the many to one bellow them, only the postid and commentid are nullable and all of them (userid, postid and commentid) have the @Index({ unique: true  }) on top of them